# Compatibility of pressure gauge with valve

Tags: tire, tire-pressure, valves

I have a tube with schrader valve, for which I want to buy a pressure gauge. Is there a specific type of nozzle for different types of valves?

How many types of such nozzles are available for different type of valves?

Are these nozzle types compatible with different type of valves?

e.g. is Schrader type nozzle compatible with presta type valve?

Comment: Any standard gauge you buy at an auto parts supplier will fit a Schrader valve.  A Presta gauge would be a specialty item you'd have to buy from a bike parts supplier.  However, the best approach is to have a floor pump with built-in gauge, and most of your better pumps have an "agnostic" chuck that will fit either Schrader or Presta.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are Presta, and Schrader valves. There are also dunlop valves but they are far less common these days, especially in the US/UK.

Schrader and Presta are two different diameters and valve types. There are pumps that will inflate either, there are also pumps that only inflate one or the other. Many people use a pump with a built in gauge rather than carrying an independent gauge. There are however gauges that will also read both valve type, they generally have two different heads, one for each type of valve.

Such as this one:

[image]

One side is for Presta and one is for Schrader. A presta will not work on a schrader and vise versa.

Comment: Thank you. That's the answer I was looking for. I think I will rather go with a pump with an individual gauge

Answer (score 6):

In addition to a dual nozzle, its possible to use an adapter on may Schrader pressure guages -  most bikes have them for a couple of dollars.

[image]

Comment: If you have presta valves, one of these should be in your on-bike toolkit.   Even if you carry the right pump/inflater.

Comment: But note that they work poorly at best, so they should not be your "first line of defense".

Comment: I had once tried such adapter with a Dunlop valve, commonly available in India. The air was leaking through it.